# why is the specificity in CSS not getting implemented in my code?

Tags: html, css, tags, css-specificity

This is my code where I was testing Specificty in CSS.The specificity of ul#Drinks is (1,0,1) wheras the specificity of .hello is (0,1,0) . Can anyone please tell why the second item of the list(Mountain Dew) is coming out to be brown and not blue ? It would be a great help

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Specificity</title>
    <style>
        .hello{
            color:brown;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: unset;
        }
       ul#Drinks{
            color:darkblue;
            font-size: 30px; 
            font-style: italic;   
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="Drinks">
        <li>fanta</li>
        <li class="hello">Mountain Dew</li>
        <li>Pepsi</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no rule of specificity in this case. You have mentioned the color directly for the `li` and hence it overrides the parent. If you had provided `ul#Drinks li` then it would have been blue.

Comment: Exactly as m4n0 said. Rule of specifity is used in other cases (when we have more rules on one element, not parent&children). For better understanding use `<li>blue <span class="hello">brown</span> blue</li>`. Nested .hello is brown, the rest of UL is blue.

Comment: Thank You Very Much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, "specificity" applies to the application of properties to a single element with multiple classes or other properties targeted by selectors (learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)). In this case, there is no concern of specificity because your `<li>` only has the single class with corresponding CSS, and its styles will override those of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Specificity</title>
    <style>
        .hello{
            color:brown;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: unset;
        }
       ul[id="Drinks"] * {
            color: darkblue;
            font-size: 30px; 
            font-style: italic;   
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="Drinks">
        <li>fanta</li>
        <li class="hello">Mountain Dew</li>
        <li>Pepsi</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```